# ASP.NET MVC Script Bundling Errors with FontAwesome 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, font-awesome, bundling-and-minification

I am starting a new MVC project and am utilizing script bundling to speed everything up. An issue I ran into is with FontAwesome 5's SVG framework, it references some paths in the Javascript that generate 404s after bundling, but work fine without bundling.

I found `CssRewriteUrlTransform` when using CSS files which helps rewrite any paths like this for CSS files so they work with the bundled path, but I'm not finding anything for Javascript ones. I can always fall back to the CSS version of FA5, but we'd rather use the SVG framework if there's a way to fix the bundling to update the paths with Javascript.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Typically here I look for the easiest solution which is to set my bundle url to the same source folder. i.e. my bundle url might be `~/content/corecss` or `~/scripts/corejs` then any files that need to be referenced within those files are in the same location. This doesn't work in every scenario though.

Comment: I actually tried that too, but for some reason bundling doesn't work then. It generates the URL for the assets as `/assets/css?v=` with no hash at the end. As soon as I use a bundle URL that doesn't exist, the hash is there and everything loads fine.